# Checking size of collection that is a property of form bean in struts

Tags: forms, tags, struts

I have a collection that is a property of Form Bean in struts.

I need to write a check on the size of that collection in jsp.

in C:IF or logic:equals, I didn't find how can I specify the form name and property and the size comparison.

Anybody good in struts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use the `notEmpty` tag from the `logic` tag-library (which is provided by the struts framework) just like @Uchenna suggested.

Or, you can directly use the `c:if` tag (with EL `${}`) from JSTL, which is also used by the `logic:notEmpty` behind the scene.

Sample:

```xml
<!-- This resolves to false even if myCollection is null -->
<c:if test="${! empty myForm.myCollection}">

</c:if>
```

Or instead of `!`, you can also use the `not` keyword (or operator).

Docs:

- [`logic:notEmpty`](http://struts.apache.org/1.x/struts-taglib/tlddoc/logic/notEmpty.html)
- [`c:if`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/if.html)

Answer (score 0):

When you forward to a jsp, the form name will be on the scope of that jsp. So just reference the form name in the jsp and the jsp will see it. Let say the name you gave the form class in struts-config.xml is MyFormName and the list property name is myList:

```
<logic:notEmpty name='MyFormName' property='myList'>


</logic:notEmpty>
```

Let me know if this solves your issue.